# How to ignore lines based on specific statement in this function which reads the data from a text file?

Tags: php

**Info about the function:** Currently it grabs last 20 lines and display info based on the requested columns from the lines.

**What I want to do**

I want to ignore lines that contain same column 5 and 13.
Example: (The both lines below should be ignored because column 5 in the first line matches column 13 and the second line is the same as the first one because first name from column 5 matches the name of the column 13)

```
1,42,16, 201,stackoverflow_user, 1, 6762160, 39799, 9817242, 6762160, 39884, 10010545,stackoverflow_user, 2, 1351147, 1165, 483259, 1351147, 1115, 241630, 0 
1,46,27, 201,[stackoverflow_user | stackoverflow_userother], 1, 4078465, 286991, 1594830, 4078465, 287036, 1643156,stackoverflow_user, 2, 1357147, 1115, 241630, 1357147, 1065, 120815, 0
```

So, the script should grab additional line and ignore the line that columns match until it can display 20 valid lines.

**This below is my actual function:**

```
    function DMMRankings()

    {
        # read a file into an array
        $lines = file('C:/path/to/file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

        # take the last 20 lines of the file -- i.e. the last 20 values in the array
        $last_ten = array_slice($lines, -20);

        #create an array for the output
        $n = 1;
        $content = '';

        foreach ($last_ten as $l) {
            # treat the data as comma-separated values
            $arr = explode(",", $l);
            # if col 5 has multiple values, take the first one
            if (preg_match("/\[(.+?) \|/", $arr[4], $matches)) {
            $arr[4] = $matches[1];
            }
            # store the data we want in an output array.
            $data = array('rank-pos' => $n++, 'rank-name' => $arr[4], 'rank-dmuser' => $arr[12]);
        $content .= Template::Load('rankinguserdm-' . ($n % 2 == 1 ? 2 : 1), $data);
        }

        $this->content = Template::Load('user_rankingsdm', array('rankings' => $content));
    }
```

Please help me out how I can do this on my current function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that will test whether col 5 and col 13 are the same, and skip the line if so. It uses an accumulator to keep a count of how many valid lines there are. See the code for comments on what it is doing.

```
# read a file into an array
$lines = file('C:/path/to/file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

# flip our array over so the last lines of the file are first.
$lines = array_reverse($lines);
$n = 0;
$wanted = 20; # or however many lines you want.
$content = '';

foreach ($lines as $l) {
   # treat the data as comma-separated values
   $arr = explode(",", $l);
   # if col 5 has multiple values, take the first one
   if (preg_match("/\[(.+?) \|/", $arr[4], $matches)) {
       $arr[4] = $matches[1];
   }
   # is arr[4] the same as arr[12]?
   if ($arr[4] !== $arr[12]) {
       # these two are not equal, so use these values
       $data = array('rank-pos' => $n++, 'rank-name' => $arr[4], 'rank-dmuser' => $arr[12]);
       $content .= Template::Load('rankinguserdm-' . ($n % 2 == 1 ? 2 : 1), $data);
   }
   # have we got enough data?
   if ($n === $wanted) {
       break;
   }
}
# check if we got enough data from the loop
if ($n < $wanted) {
    die("We couldn't get enough data!");
}
```

Comment: He only grabs 20 lines from the file: `$last_ten = array_slice($lines, -20);` So if one fails he can never have one more.

Comment: And for that reason it's messed up. Thanks a lot but for some reason it display incorrectly: it starts - 1st,2nd,3rd,25th,29th when it should only display from 1 to 20. What may cause that?

Comment: What are your requirements -- do you want 10 valid lines or 20 valid lines? It was 10, which was why I put in the break when n = 10.

Comment: @Monk25 You should also post a chunk of the data file that you're using so that we can check that the data isn't causing the problem.

Comment: actually you're right. i use 10 lines but since 2 lines have same columns, it display only 8. possible to loop until it display 10 valid lines if exist? also, actually if the text file doesnt exist or not enough lines, it wont produce error right? so I can be safe that it will work or simply dont display anything if there aren't enough lines/ 0 lines or file doesnt exist?

Comment: I've edited the code -- you can set `$wanted` to whatever you like. You have to define what you want the code to do if there aren't enough lines--it (and I) can't magically guess what you want to happen. You can add some code that will make the script die or display nothing if some part of the process fails.

Comment: Thanks man. It's appreciated, so last thing before I can accept the answer. I wanna ask the following: `If file doesn't exist --> display nothing`, `if file exist but no lines --> display nothing`, `if file exist but not enough lines --> display which lines are there only.` It's what it does by default at this moment when I remove the `# check if we got enough data from the loop` is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Comment out the "die" and it will just display the information that it does have.

Comment: So, it's safe to comment it out and it wont error if there aren't enough lines or anything like that, correct? Also, last thing --> sometimes I receive line like that: `1,42,16, 201,[stackoverflow_user], 1, 6762160, 39799, 9817242, 6762160, 39884, 10010545,stackoverflow_user, 2, 1351147, 1165, 483259, 1351147, 1115, 241630, 0` As you can see it has single username but its between `[]` how to make sure they are removed `[]` as well if it detect that? So, it display the username normally without the `[]` THANKS A LOT MAN!

Comment: Just use `trim` to strip them--`trim($text, '[]')`. FYI, I am not a man. :)

Comment: Sorry for the `man` part. Please take my apologize. It's awesome for the help you provide for me. It's really appreciated. Now I only need to find out a way to make big file reading better since as I saw in previous comments the `file()` will affect the performance or maybe `array_reverse()` is workaround on that?

Comment: I would see how this performs first. If it starts getting slow, you probably want to think about moving to a database, rather than storing data in a file. The kind of queries you want to do are easy in a database.

Comment: `I understand, so it shouldn't overload by a lot for approximately 1 mb file with around 5,000 - 6,000 lines, right?` And last thing that I am struggling is how to display the data from the lines in DESC ORDER? So, last lines info will display as first ?

Comment: actually I found that it works the way I want at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

To get 20 valid lines, just keep looping till you have 20.

```
$lastline=count($lines);
$dsp=0;

while(dsp<20){
      //check to see if there are any more lines
      if(!$lines[$lastline-$dsp]){
              echo 'oops, we ran out of lines';
              break;}
      $l=$lines[$lastline-$dsp];
        # treat the data as comma-separated values
        $arr = explode(",", $l);
        # if col 5 has multiple values, take the first one
        if (preg_match("/\[(.+?) \|/", $arr[4], $matches)) {
            $arr[4] = $matches[1];
            }
        //skip if 5==13
        if($arr[4]==$arr[12])continue;

        //else: add one to counter
        $dsp++;

        # store the data we want in an output array.
        $data = array('rank-pos' => $n++, 'rank-name' => $arr[4], 'rank-dmuser' => $arr[12]);
    $content .= Template::Load('rankinguserdm-' . ($n % 2 == 1 ? 2 : 1), $data);
    }
```

Comment: The OP already has `$n` as an accumulator - you can use that.